# Ajax submit Form serialized data in php are null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I ve been searching all relative questions here and still cant figure out the problem I have.

I am using a simple modal form :

```
     <p id="messages">Let's make today a great day!</p>
<form id="myloginform" name="myloginform" action="scripts/login.php" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="">Enter username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg c-square" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"  required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="">Enter pass</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg c-square" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="c-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="login-rememberme" class="c-check">
    <label for="login-rememberme" class="c-font-thin c-font-17">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn btn-md c-btn-uppercase c-btn-bold c-btn-square c-btn-login" id="check">login</button>

    </div>

    </form>
```

I am using ajax to pass the form to a php file :

```
     <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

            $('form#myloginform').submit(function(e) {

                var my_data = $('form#myloginform').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : 'scripts/login.php',
                    cache       : false,
                    data        : my_data,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(response) {
                        //TARGET THE MESSAGES DIV IN THE MODAL
                        if(response.type == 'success') {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response.message);
                        } else {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The login.php file is very simple and returns an json $output response

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username == "Test"){
    $success = true;
    }

if($success == true) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'message' => $username));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'message' => $username));
}

die($output);
?>
```

The $output in every case returns null. I checked with firebug, and everything is OK , no errors, POST perfect still I cannot get the variables in php to work. Any ideas ??? Is something wrong with my approach or do I need to deserialize the data in the php file , somehow...???

Comment: Remove the `contentType` and `processData` options, you've just turned off everything jQuery uses to parse the serialized form into www-urlencoded data before it's sent to the server.

Comment: Perfect, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use die. 
Use echo or print. 

Also set contentType to true.